# Assign list of remote authorized_keys files to local variable

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

I would like to assign a list of remote authorized keys files to a local variable.

```
INCLUDE=$(ssh myhost.mydomain.com "for Z in `awk -F : '{print $1}' /etc/passwd`; do INCLUDE+=\"/home/${Z}/.ssh/authorized_keys \"; done; echo $INCLUDE")
```

How can I correctly escape the above command to make it a valid request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this statement you get some strange result like /home/bin, /home/root or /home/daemon.

```
for Z in `awk -F : '{print $1}' /etc/passwd`; do INCLUDE+="/home/${Z}/.ssh/authorized_keys "
```

`ls /home/*/.ssh/authorized_keys` fits better.

So the resulting script could be:

```
INCLUDE=$(ssh root@myhost.mydomain.com "ls /home/*/.ssh/authorized_keys")
```

But you need connect as a root to ssh-server

Comment: That is more elegant for sure, however this returns only my authorized_keys file.  I've also tried with sudo and had the same result.

Comment: Add the comment about root

Comment: While I wait for peer review, I've updated the above answer to work with sudo as enabling root ssh is probably not a good idea:
`INCLUDE=$(ssh myhost.mydomain.com "sudo su -c 'ls /home/*/.ssh/authorized_keys'")`

Answer (score 0):

```
sgeorge-mn:~ sgeorge$ cat awk_ssh.sh 
ssh -q suku@192.168.97.128 <<'HERE'
cat /etc/passwd | grep '/bin/bash'| awk -F: '{system("ls /home/"$1"/.ssh/authorized_keys")}'
HERE

sgeorge-mn:~ sgeorge$ INCLUDE=$(bash awk_ssh.sh)
suku@192.168.97.128's password: 

sgeorge-mn:~ sgeorge$ echo $INCLUDE
/home/root/.ssh/authorized_keys /home/suku/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Answer (score 0):

The most error-prone method would be actually get each user's HOME dir from passwd database and check it for `authorized_keys` files. Also note that openssh supports both `authorized_keys` AND `authorized_keys2` files.

This command should give such list:

```
getent passwd | awk -F: '$6!=""{print $6}' | \
    xargs -rI{} find {} -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 \
        -path \*/.ssh/\* \
        \( -name authorized_keys -o -name authorized_keys2 \) \
        -type f 2>/dev/null
```

You have to escape quotes appropriately if you're going to execute it via ssh. However, you can put it in script file and feed it to `/bin/sh` on the remote side:

```
<scriptfile ssh remote.host /bin/sh
```